# using the results of a function outside of it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that im working on to serve me some statistics for a server:

```
const os = require('os');

//Create function to get CPU information
function cpuAverage() {

    //Initialise sum of idle and time of cores and fetch CPU info
    var totalIdle = 0, totalTick = 0;
    var cpus = os.cpus();

    //Loop through CPU cores
    for (var i = 0, len = cpus.length; i < len; i++) {

        //Select CPU core
        var cpu = cpus[i];

        //Total up the time in the cores tick
        for (type in cpu.times) {
            totalTick += cpu.times[type];
        }

        //Total up the idle time of the core
        totalIdle += cpu.times.idle;
    }

    //Return the average Idle and Tick times
    return {idle: totalIdle / cpus.length, total: totalTick / cpus.length};
}

// function to calculate average of array
const arrAvg = function (arr) {
    if (arr && arr.length >= 1) {
        const sumArr = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        return sumArr / arr.length;
    }
};

// load average for the past 1000 milliseconds calculated every 100
function getCPULoadAVG(avgTime = 1000, delay = 100) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const n = ~~(avgTime / delay);
        if (n <= 1) {
            reject('Error: interval to small');
        }

        let i = 0;
        let samples = [];
        const avg1 = cpuAverage();

        let interval = setInterval(() => {

            if (i >= n) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(~~((arrAvg(samples) * 100)));
            }

            const avg2 = cpuAverage();
            const totalDiff = avg2.total - avg1.total;
            const idleDiff = avg2.idle - avg1.idle;

            samples[i] = (1 - idleDiff / totalDiff);

            i++;

        }, delay);

    });

}

getCPULoadAVG(1000, 100).then((cb)=>{
    console.log(cb);
});
```

i want to use the result of said code outside of it, but im unable to declare a global variable outside of it that will be able to attain its data.
What i can use to extract the results of the variable cb so i can utilize it outside of this function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your `console.log(cb)` statement already is outside of the `getCPULoadAVG` function, what more do you want? But no, you cannot get the future value outside of the callback, having it travel back in time.